Can we find useful, standard search filters?
Search filters
Having recently discovered the power of SE's relatively extensive Advanced Search feature, thanks to Jeromy, I want to ask what if any search filters you use regularly when browsing CogSci?
We all have a finite amount of time to spend here, so I think being able to efficiently find good questions to answers, and good answers to upvote, is an important piece of our community knowledge. It would be great if we could find a few standard search filters that are particularly diagnostic of different types of posts (e.g., new posts that need attention).
Which search filters do you use to help browse CogSci more efficiently? If you weren't aware them before, like I wasn't, can you think of any particularly useful or diagnostic ones?
Search filter examples

Questions without answers or upvotes. Obvious.
New answers with zero score. Obvious.
Favorites. Finally a use for favorites! I could never find them.


What about the default review queues?

@StevenJeuris I think most people already know about those.

I like questions with no votes and no answers that are neither duplicate nor closed.  

Unanswered questions with at least 500 views. It's easy to adjust the # of views to be more or less strict.

Not-closed, not-duplicate questions with no answers within a tag (e.g., working-memory).
